# I am trying to display array but system.string[] shows up

Tags: c#

I am just starting to learn c# and I do not know much except simple concepts, but right now I am learning about strings and splits and I am trying to display a simple array I can't really explain much since I know so little but here is the code and maybe someone can help

```
namespace stringSplit
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] separator = { ", ", "; " };
            string names = "Peter, John; Andy, , David";
            string[] substrings = names.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);

            Console.Write(names);
            Console.ReadLine();

            string[] substrings2 = names.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            Console.Write(substrings);
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write(substrings2);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot just say write <array here> you have to write out the individual elements of it

Comment: you need a for loop that will loop through the elements of the array and show them individually.

Comment: How would I do this, sorry I'm really new

Comment: Thank you to everyone that posted I have gotten an answer and a cool little thing to put everything into one string I will definitely post more often if I have more questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a foreach loop to display every item in a string array:

```
foreach (var item in substrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
Console.ReadLine();
foreach (var item in substrings2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to `Write` each element separately

```
foreach (string item in substrings)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

---

Concartenate the array into a single string

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", substrings));
```

---

Or you could use the [`Array.ForEach<T> Method (T[], Action<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the [`Array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx) class

```
Array.ForEach(substrings, Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just display a array via `Console.WriteLine()` you have to name the index i.e `exampleStringArray[1]` or have to iterate via `foreach`

the easiest way to write all the values from the string array would be `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", substrings));` to have it comma seperated or

```
foreach (string item in substrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

The `Console.WriteLine()` tries to call the `.ToString()` and since it is not defined to take a whole array, it will just return the type.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `Write` the whole array, you may however iterate over it to get each element written:

```
public static void Main()
{
        string[] separator = { ", ", "; " };
        string names = "Peter, John; Andy, David";
        string[] substrings = names.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);

        foreach(var name in substrings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }

}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

[dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qdDFdT)